# INCLUDED HTML files javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

The Scenario of my program is when I submit the form, form action goes to `xyz.php`.
In `xyz.php`, I just used
`INCLUDE("abc.html")` to redirect to another HTML page, now the `abc.html` is containing some HTML tags and also the **"JAVASCRIPT"**, But when my form got submitted the page redirected to `abc.html`.
The `abc.html` contains HTML and Javascript code. HTML content is visible but javascript is not working,

I am new in PHP. Thank you

Below is "student.php" FILE

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Marks Entering</title>
</head>  
<body>
   <?php 

     $con1= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','student');
     $con2= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','first_year');
     $con3= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','computer_dep');



     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {  

        $query1 = "SELECT MAX(`ID`) as 'ID', `Last_Name`, `Middle_Name`, `first_Name`, `DOB`, `Department`, `Semester` FROM `student`";
        $run = mysqli_query($con1,$query1);




        if($run == TRUE)
        {
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
            $ID=$data['ID'];
            $name= $data['Last_Name'] . " " . $data['Middle_Name'] . " " .$data['first_Name'];
            $sem= $data['Semester'];


            switch($sem)
            {
                case 1:
                echo "sem1 not have mark";

                    break;

                case 2:

                    $m1=$_POST['m_i'];
                    $ph=$_POST['ph'];
                    $bee=$_POST['bee'];
                    $em=$_POST['em'];
                    $evs=$_POST['evs'];
                    $cm=$_POST['cm'];



                    $query2="INSERT INTO `sem1`(`Id`,`Name`,`M1`,`PHYSICS1`,`CHEM1`,`BEE`,`EM`,`EVS`) VALUES ($ID,'$name',$m1,$ph,$cm,$bee,$em,$evs)";

                    $run1 = mysqli_query($con2,$query2);

                    if($run1 == TRUE)
                    {
                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('Submitted Successfully!!!!')" ;

                        include("teachdata.html");
                    }
                    else {
                            echo mysqli_error($con2);
                        }

                    break;      
            }




        }   

     } 

     ?>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Here IS "teachdata.html"

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Data Entry</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teachdata.css">
    <script src="teachtab.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Welcome teacher section.....</h1>

    <div class="solid">

            <div class="tab">
                 <hr>
                <p style="margin-left: 40px; text-width:5px ; text-shadow: 0 0 3px  #ffb3b3, 0 0 5px  #ffe6e6;"><b> Menu</b> </p>
                <hr style="color:white">
                <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablink" onclick="opentab(event,'home')">Home</button>
                <button class="tablink" onclick="opentab(event,'Info')">Add Information</button>
                <button class="tablink" onclick="opentab(event,'Marks')">Add Marks</button>
                <button class="tablink" onclick="opentab(event,'Update')">Update</button>

            </div>

            <div id="home" class="tabcontent">
                <hr>
                   <p style="text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FF0000; text-align:center;">Instruction's</p>
                 <hr>

            </div>

            <div id="Info" class="tabcontent">
                  <hr>
                   <p style="text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FF0000; text-align:center;">Information</p>
                  <hr> 

                  <form action="student.php" method="post">

                    <label>Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="lname" class="space"> 
                    <label>Middle Name:</label>  <input type="text" name="mname" class="space"> 
                    <label>first Name:</label>  <input type="text" name="fname" class="space"></br></br>



                    <label > DOB:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="bday"> </br></br>

                    <label>Department:</label>  
                    <select name="department" class="space">
                        <option value="comp">Computer Engineering</option>
                        <option value="it">IT Engineering</option>
                        <option value="civil">Civil Engineering</option>
                        <option value="mech">Mechanical Engineering</option>
                        <option value="extc">Electronics Engineering</option>
                        <option value="auto">Automobile Engineeering </option>

                    </select></br></br>

                    SEM:
                    <select name="semno">
                        <option value="1">SEM I</option>
                        <option value="2">SEM II</option>
                        <option value="3">SEM III</option>
                        <option value="4">SEM IV</option>
                        <option value="5">SEM V</option>
                        <option value="6">SEM VI</option>
                        <option value="7">SEM VII</option>
                        <option value="8">SEM VIII</option>

                    </select>   


                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> 





            </div>
            <div id="Marks" class="tabcontent">
                   <hr>
                   <p style="text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FF0000; text-align:center;">Marks</p>
                  <hr> 
            </div>

            <div id="Update"  class="tabcontent">
                    <hr>
                   <p style="text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FF0000; text-align:center;">Update</p>
                  <hr> 
            </div>





    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below Is "teachtab.js"

```
function opentab( evt,tabName)
  {
     var tabcontent,tablinks,i;

     tabcontent=document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
     for( i=0; i< tabcontent.length ;i++)
     {
          tabcontent[i].style.display= "none";
     }

     tablinks=document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
     for( i=0; i< tablinks.length ; i++)
    {
          tablinks[i].className= tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
     }

     document.getElementById(tabName).style.display="block";
     evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

  }
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Comment: can you post some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think it would be useful to see a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) As with most questions on SO you will always get a better response if you post some code

Comment: how is this accessed as, an HTTP protocol or as `file:///`? question's unclear for a few reasons

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. now i just tried to add more detail of my question

Comment: after `alert('Submitted Successfully!!!!')"` you are missing a `;` and also don't close the `<script>` tag, so js after that will throw an error I suppose. Check Console for errors!

Comment: "teachdata.html" is "Teacher.html", right?? If so, then you add another `<html>` and `<body>`, which isn't valid. Check the resulting source-code in your browser to see what you've acutally built!

Comment: Yes mistake is there teachdata.html instead of Teacher.html

Comment: After submitting form my program is redirecting to "teachdata.html" but there are only tags are working no javascript is working

Comment: Because `<script src="teachtab.js"></script>` is _not_ in the actual, active `head` of the html. As I said, you now have two, only the first is valid. Maybe you want to redirect instead of a include?? would be `header("location: teachdata.html");`

Comment: Thank you,I already use Header but in that case My alert function is not working.

Comment: But i want to use alert also to inform user that his data is submitted successfully. What can i do now

Comment: include the js in the main html page (student.php)

Comment: If possible please update my code, because i am not actually getting you, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the most simple - but not good to keep - solution.

Include the js in your main script:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Marks Entering</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teachdata.css">
   <script src="teachtab.js"></script>
</head>  
<!-- keep the rest -->
```

In teachdata.html get rid of the `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>`, keep everything from

```
<h1> Welcome teacher section.....</h1>

<!-- to -->

</div>
```

**BUT** it would be much better to redirect to `teachdata.html` (or make it a php script `teachdata.php` and include a message there).

```
    if($run1 == true) {
        header("Location: teachdata.php?msg=success");
    } else {
    //....
```

In teachdata.php you now could display the message inline as normal html

```
   <?php
   if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
       echo "<div>Message: " . $_GET['msg'] . "</div>";
   }
   ?>
```

or do a plain old javascript alert if you really want that:

```
   <?php
   if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
       echo "<script> alert('" . $_GET['msg'] . "'); </script>";
   }
   ?>
```

*More Sidenotes:*

- Please look into prepared stements. Your code is unsecure, wide open
  to sql injection (google "Bobby Tables" and "Sql Injection").
- Are you sure you need 3 different databases for your app?

Comment: Thank you so much.